# C++ Object Slicing smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, derived-class

Hi I am using the following code to read an Image class which is derived from cv::Mat. Then I want to pass the object into a function where I pass it directly into a vector of smart pointers to cv::Mat.
In that way supposedly I should avoid object slicing. However that is not the case.The example is a bit simplified in relation to the real version.

```
class Image : public cv::Mat {

public:
    Image(cv::Mat m) : cv::Mat(m)  {}
    Image() : cv::Mat() {}

    std::string labelGen;
    int labelNum;
};

std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat> getImage(char *readPath) {

    std::shared_ptr<Image> i(new Image(cv::imread(readPath, 0)));
    i->labelGen = "String";
    i->labelNum = 5;

    return i;
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>> getVectors() { 


    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>> v;
    v.push_back(getImage("path/path.jpg"));

    return v;
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong;

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, this is all right. How do you figure there was slicing? Maybe the problem is somewhere else in the code you are not showing

Comment: if right after the pushback I do a std::string s = static_cast<Image> (*vec[0]).labelGen; then I just get an empty string

Comment: Well, that's because you are casting a `Mat` object to an `Image` object: indeed that gives you slicing. Try `shared_ptr<Image> spImage = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Image>(vec[0]); spImage->labelGen;`

Comment: The diagnosis is the cause: The static_cast<Image> slices, not the vector push back. try static_cast<const Image&>.

Comment: @user1847708: I think you need a virtual destructor for `Image` as well. Although it is probably correct in your real code.

Comment: static_cast<const Image&> worked. Pretty logical now that I think of it since I was casting to an object and not a memory location.

Comment: You don't need a virtual destructor, shared_ptr will do the right thing and not simply call delete on the pointer-to-cv::Mat. It would be cleaner to have one though. If you don't have one, cv::Mat isn't designed as a baseclass and I'd rather suggest aggregation than derivation. BTW: Use a "cv::Mat const&" as argument to the constructor to avoid another unnecessary copy.